# How do i wait until a condition is given in LOVE2D?

Tags: lua, wait, repeat, love2d

I've tried

```
timer.script(function(wait)
repeat
    wait(0)
until condiction
end)
```

but it didn't work. Please help me!

Comment: that didn't work is not a proper error description. Please read [ask]
also it is not clear what you are waiting for and if you want to do something else while waiting or not. you should also provide more code and context. what is timer.script? I can only assume that it is from the HUMP library and if, what do you expect to happen if you do nothing but wait for 0 seconds?

Comment: Are you looking for a function to be called on a given event (i.e. a callback function for a keypress that fires every time a key is pressed) or something akin to a do-while loop?

Comment: i used hump.timer and timer.script is a way to use `wait` instead of `timer.after`

Answer (score 0):

[timer.script](http://hump.readthedocs.io/en/latest/timer.html#Timer.script) is not really designed for what you're trying to do, though it *might* be possible to get it to work.

The LÖVE framework is built around the `draw()` and `update()` callbacks and I would recommend learning how to do this task with just these callbacks, before moving on to methods that layer on top of these callbacks. Something like this should run your code only once, when your condition is first met:

```
local hasHappened = false
function love.update(dt)
  if (condition and not hasHappened) then
    hasHappened = true
    -- respond to condition here
  end
end
```

Typically, you wouldn't check your condition directly in `love.update()`. Instead, you would have a table that contains all the objects in your game, and in `love.update()` you loop through this table of objects and call an `update()` method on each one. That gives each object a chance to check for different conditions and respond to them.

An alternative approach would be to name your condition and to use an event system like [beholder](https://github.com/kikito/beholder.lua) to trigger the event (and any callback functions that are registered) when the condition happens.

Or (provided your timer's update() is being called in `love.update()`), you could do it with your timer object and the `every()` method:

```
local handle = timer:every(0.01, function()
  if condition then
    -- unregister timer, assuming you only want the code to be run once
    timer:cancel(handle)

    -- respond to condition here
  end
end)
```

Comment: How do i use timer.cancel?

Comment: arturgps2: A `timer` is actually more like a clock than a timer, since it manages multiple timers simultaneously. In order to cancel a timer, like the `every()` in the code sample above, you need to store a handle (a reference) to that particular `:every()` timer, as is done above, and pass that as the first argument to `cancel()`. Note the use of the colon `:cancel` instead of the dot notation `.cancel`, since this is a method call. That's about all I can think of, if you have more questions, you'll need to be a bit more specific.

Comment: Actually i forgot to `timer.update` into `love.update`,but this suggestion helped me too. Thanks for the help.